# Why Airway packages is not installing in R?

Tags: r, install.packages

I want to install airway packages in R. But it is not happening

I want to install airway packages in R. But it is not happening. It is showing the following:
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘airway’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: `install.packages()` installs packages from CRAN. It does not look like `airway` is a CRAN package, it appears to be a bioconductor package. Installation instructions are available on the package home page: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/html/airway.html